# How to make a sequence of functions in REBOL?

Tags: rebol

I'd like to collect various functions in a sequence and activate them by the sequence index, like in this simple example:

```
mul2: func [n] [2 * n]
mul3: func [n] [2 * n]
...
(pick [mul2 mul3] 1) 2 ; yields 2
```

It seems that `mul2` is not treated like a function when it's referred to as a sequence item:

```
type? (pick [mul2] 1) == word!
```

Is it possible to arrange functions into sequences?

While experiencing with this example, I noticed that

```
function? mul2
```

complains that the argument of `mul2` is missing, instead of returning `true`. Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mul2` and `mul3` are just words

```
mul2: func [n] [2 * n]
mul3: func [n] [3 * n]

w: pick [mul2 mul3] 1
type? w
; == word!
```

When you `get` it's value, then you'll have the function:

```
f: get pick [mul2 mul3] 1
; == func [n][2 * n]

type? :f
; == function!

function? :f
; == true
```

Notice that I used `:f` (get-word) to get the unevaluated value (the function itself) instead of `f`, because `f` will be evaluated and will require its parameters.

And then you can use `f`:

```
f 6
; == 12
```

Comment: And same for `function? :mul2`

Comment: endo64, thank you for your answer. It seems I need to study the specifics of words. It's still confusing why items change behavior when put into a list, as in `a: 1 b: [a a]. `type? pick b 1`  yields `word!`, while `type? a` yields `integer!`.

Comment: It is because words in a block is not evaluated until you ask for. When you type `type? a`, `a` is evaluated to `1` and then `type?` returns `integer!` for the value `1`.
`type? pick b 1` is like `type? 'a`